# css code for IE and Firefox

Tags: css

i have a css code which works on Chrome very well,

```
   .glow {
        -webkit-animation-duration: 1s;
        -webkit-animation-name: glow;
        -webkit-animation-direction: alternate;
        -webkit-animation-iteration-count: infinite;
        animation-duration: 1s;
        animation-name: glow;
        animation-direction: alternate;
        animation-iteration-count: infinite;
        color: white;
        font-family: 'Limelight', cursive;
        font-size: 90px;
        z-index: 555;
        padding-top:25px;
    }

    @-webkit-keyframes glow {
        from { text-shadow: 0 0 5px maroon; }
        to { text-shadow: 0 0 15px maroon; }
    }
```

I am a complete novice to css, can you please help me understand what changes needs to be done to make this work on Internet Explorer & firefox.

Thanks and pardon me if I am violating SO rules by posting a question without trying.

[**JSFiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/lakshman553/55vrLp6c/)

laks.

Comment: Check my answer, I tested it on Chrome and Firefox, you try it on IE. My code works for me!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this. I used a auto-prefixer for cross-browser compatibility:

```
.glow {
    -webkit-animation-duration: 1s;
            animation-duration: 1s;
    -webkit-animation-name: glow;
            animation-name: glow;
    -webkit-animation-direction: alternate;
            animation-direction: alternate;
    -webkit-animation-iteration-count: infinite;
            animation-iteration-count: infinite;
    -webkit-animation-duration: 1s;
            animation-duration: 1s;
    -webkit-animation-name: glow;
            animation-name: glow;
    -webkit-animation-direction: alternate;
            animation-direction: alternate;
    -webkit-animation-iteration-count: infinite;
            animation-iteration-count: infinite;
    color: white;
    font-family: 'Limelight', cursive;
    font-size: 90px;
    z-index: 555;
    padding-top:25px;
}

@-webkit-keyframes glow {
    from { text-shadow: 0 0 5px maroon; }
    to { text-shadow: 0 0 15px maroon; }
}

@keyframes glow {
    from { text-shadow: 0 0 5px maroon; }
    to { text-shadow: 0 0 15px maroon; }
}
```